# Is this an amaranthus?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health

Google lens identifies it as a amaranthus tricolor, but it doesn’t look quite right.
[image]

Comment: Are you more concerned about whether it's in the Amaranthus genus or whether it's Amaranthus tricolor?

Comment: I just want to know what it is.

Comment: It looks to me like Coleus tricolour. I have one in my garden too, which looks similar, except that mine has red/maroon patches and yours has violet.